# Openshift Backup - Server Not Reachable

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, openshift-php-cartidges

I had openshift 2 starter account where I had my application running.
Openshift 2 been shut down and now I got mail to migrate it to 3
But I don't have backup of an application

I am getting following errors

- Upon `rhc save-snapshot myapp` I am getting following error.

> Error in trying to save snapshot. You can try to save manually by
>   running: ssh 54f03dbd4382ec9101000159@myapp-myapps.rhcloud.com
>   'snapshot' > myapp.tar.gz

- If I try to ssh application then connection is getting closed.

  `ssh 54f03dbd4382ec9101000159@myapp-myapps.rhcloud.com`

> Connection to myapp-myapps.rhcloud.com closed.

- If I try to restart application from console then I am getting error

> could not open session
>
> could not open session
>
> could not open session Failed to execute: 'control restart' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/54f03dbd4382ec9101000159/mysql Failed to execute:
>   'control restart' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/54f03dbd4382ec9101000159/phpmyadmin Failed to
>   execute: 'control restart' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/54f03dbd4382ec9101000159/php

EDIT : I get following error in browser when I try to open my site.

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at www.mydomain.com Port 80

Need your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: There is currently an issue with taking the snapshots for a backup. It is being investigated and a fix worked out. Try again later.

Comment: Thanks for Information. May I have any link to Official Notification ? Is SSH also not working ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where one can see information tracking the issue. I am assuming that since instances have been shutdown that there would be no SSH access.

Comment: My instance was shut down too. Do you know if there is any way to backup my postgresql database?

Comment: Still not possible to backup it? Any one could do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a new post on OpenShift [blog](https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/):

> Updated October 3, 2017
>
> We understand how important your data is, and
>   we have made a one-time exception to allow you to access your
>   OpenShift Online v2 data. You have until October 5, 2017 at 4:00 PM
>   UTC to perform a backup of your application. If you have not used it
>   before, you can download the rhc tool here.

Then you can perform your backup until the 2017/10/05.

Answer (score 0):

Reading around (don't know exactly where) I found that the payed accounts still working until decebmber 31th, so I updated to bronze and could restart the service and backup it. Don't know exactly if is because the upgrade or if was fixed some issue.